# Why does prettier add an extra pair of parentheses here?

Tags: javascript, format, boolean, do-while, prettier

I was trying to format a block of code like this one:

```
let [a, b] = [64n, 2n];
do {
    console.log(a);
} while (a /= b);
```

I found that prettier adds an extra pair of parentheses around the `while` condition:

```
let [a, b] = [64n, 2n];
do {
    console.log(a);
} while ((a /= b));
```

I don't get why it does that. Seems like a bug, since both pieces of code give the same output. Is there any reason to prefer the second format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `while(<expression>)` and `while((<expression>))` will always be equivalent. However, it seems that Prettier is intentionally adding an extra wrapping parenthesis because the condition is an assignment.

Documented in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5591). Here is what lydell said in December 2018

> Hi! This is actually intentional, since it is a common convention to wrap assignments in conditions in extra parens to show that you actually meant to use assignment (`=`) instead of comparision (`===`) (which is an easy mistake to make). For example, the [no-cond-assign](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-cond-assign) ESLint rule has an `except-parens` option for this case.